# List R variable names and their SEXP in the global env during debugging of compiled C/C++ code (GDB)

Tags: r, gdb, rcpp

The context of this question is debugging of an R packages that calls C or C++ code (eg. via the package `Rcpp` or directly using the R API) by using `gdb` (or another) debugger.

How can I list the variable names and find their `SEXP` pointers to print the values of variables in the global env of R during low-level debugging at C/C++ level using eg. gdb as debugger?

I am using the work flow documented in [Writing R Extensions > Debugging of compiled code](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Debugging-compiled-code)

```
R -d gdb
```

which mentions how to print `SEXP`ressions via

```
(gdb) p R_PV(mySEXPRvar)
(gdb) call Rf_PrintValue(mySEXPRvar)
```

but how can I list the variables like the R command `ls` does?

**Edit 1:** There is a code example in the Rcpp gallery which shows how to access the global env programmatically (but I would prefer to do this only whithin the debugger):
https://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/accessing-environments/

Comment: Maybe [this](https://teuder.github.io/rcpp4everyone_en/290_environment.html) has the info you need.

Comment: @Oliver THX for the ebook link (didn't know about this great book until now :-) What I am trying to achieve is debugging without modifying the package under debugging (which possibly even uses only the R API without Rcpp) and the Rcpp code snippet would require to recompile (or create a separate debugging package) to inject debugging helper functions.

Comment: I think you keep wishing for things to be a certain way.  Have you considered that maybe compilers just don't work the same way an interpreted environment like R does?  I still think you best bet may be the Python-extensible scripting of `gdb`.  I really think you question call for _someone to add functionality for you at the compiler level_ and there is very little indeed that Rcpp can do for you.  We all like free lunches, but I think by now we looked all over the park...

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel In fact I am trying to collect the building bricks for an easy-to-use solution which I am willing to contribute if I find something (perhaps a debugging helper package that offers simple non-templated debugging functions for finding and printing R variables, `SEXP`s and `Rcpp` data types incl. a how-to-debug tutorial - this could be loaded via `library` or perhaps just a part of that via `dyn.load`)  so please bare with me :-) `gdb` pretty printers via Python don't seem to help since (as you said) I cannot change compiler behavior which reorgs or throws away code/symbols...

Comment: That would be Yuge indeed so keep plugging away!  Just wanted to make sure you don't expect us to merely juggle the magic pixie dust shaker which, sadly, is empty.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I have set up a repo so watch my (possibly slow) progress...: https://github.com/aryoda/R_CppDebugHelper